# Jquery: if any .siblings().position().top is equal to $(this).position().top

Tags: javascript, jquery, position, each, siblings

I have the following html:

```
<div class="container" id="1"></div>
<div class="container" id="2"></div>
<div class="container" id="3"></div>

<div class="details" id="1"></div>
<div class="details" id="2"></div>
<div class="details" id="3"></div>
```

and jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.container').each(function () {
            $(this).click(function () {
                var elem = $(this),
                    containerId = elem.attr('id'),
                    activeId = $(containerId + '.active');
                $(this).toggleClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
                $('#details-' + containerId).toggleClass('visible').siblings().removeClass('visible');
            });
    });
});
```

What I'm trying to do is see if any other .container div has the same position top as the active container (the one I just clicked). If they don't have the same top position, then I'll slide them down and display the details in full width.

So I'm thinking that something like this should work - $(this) meaning the active .container div :

```
if($(this).siblings().position().top == $(this).position().top) {
// add some class to EACH sibling that has equal top position
}
```

but I'm not entirely sure how to do it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to something like

```
var top = $(this).position().top;

var $sibs = $(this).siblings().filter(function(){
    return $(this).position().top == top
})
//do something with the matching siblings refferred by $sibs
```

`$(this).siblings().position().top` will return the `top` value of the first sibling elements, it will not check the value of rest of the siblings.